# How should I handle users changing their avatar in Firebase storage?

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage

What should be the right thing to do when a user changes their avatar? Should I keep avatar photos in a folder named as the user's uid, and save each photo there with it's actual name? Or should I keep all avatars in one folder with their name being the uid of the user they belong to?

If I go with the second would I end up having issues with token or something as I've overwritten an existing file?
If I go with the first, how do I delete the previous profile photo, if all I have saved in the DB is the download url of the image? Should I just keep a field of the actual name of the photo? It feels like too much to keep it just for deletion purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the avatars to be public for all, I suggest putting them on an avatar folder and the file name should be the uid of the user.

Generally, if you just want a specific user to have access to files then you need to enforce firebase rules to the storage collection. In that case, you should really think about how to structure your storage collection.

In the DB you should save them with the filename because you will know the location of the files in the storage you can use it to reference it. File URLs can expire or be revoked.